# Kubuntu 21.10 , how do I unhide an SD drive I hide while inside the Dolphine file manager?

Tags: sd-card

So, I right clicked on my SD card/drive and selected hide and the SD card/drive become hidden. The only problem is now I can't figure out how to unhide the SD drive.

The SD card is located in an SD card reader that is part of my laptop hardware/ports.

Hopefully someone can help this linux newbie unhide an SD card.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I had to right click in the left hand side/pane of Dolphin and select "Show Hidden Places" which showed the SD card/drive. Then I right clicked on SD card/drive to un-hide it.